# Any Javascript event for form population?

Tags: javascript, forms, dom-events

I need to call Javascript function after form value gets populated from the backend. So far I went through [these Javascript events](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp). I don't see any existing events I can use for this purpose.

I don't want a jQuery based solution. Any ideas how I can do this simply?

Edit:
I am populating the values in Java (Spring boot) in the backend. I am not having problems with populating the values to the screen. I want to know whether I can call any Javascript event after the values have been populated in the screen.

Edit2:

```
enter <form action=# th:action="@{/main}" name="Form2"  th:object="${formObject}" 
             method="post">
                <table 
                    id="collateral_position_table">
                    <tr class="header">
                        <th style="text-align: left" colspan="4"
                            id="collateral_position_title">Collateral Position</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td >NPV</td>
                        <td ><input 
                        name="otherNpv" id="otherNpv"
                        th:value="${collateralAppliqueInputForm.otherNPV}"
                        style="text-align:right" type="text"/></td>
                        <td >NPV As Of Date</td>                            
                        <td><input 
                        name="otherAsOfDate" id="otherAsOfDate"
                        th:value="${collateralAppliqueInputForm.otherAsOfDate}"
                            style="text-align:right" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4"><input 
                        type="submit" value="Update" name="action"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table> 
            </form> here
```

And the controller to populate this form

> @RequestMapping(value = {"/main"}, method = RequestMethod.POST,params="action=Update")
> public String updateForm( @Valid @ModelAttribute(value = "formObject") FormObject formObject, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,BindingResult result, Model model, Principal principal) {
>
> formObject=methodToPopulateTheForm();
>
> model.addAttribute("formObject", formObject);
>
> }

Comment: *"after form value gets populated from the backend"* How exactly does this happen? Isn't it your code that sets the values?

Comment: Do you have any code that you've tried that you can provide? Are you loading a form and then wanting a JS event to fire after form is populated? Are you populating the form with JS, or PHP, etc?

Comment: _I need to call javascript function after form value gets populated from the backend_ no `onPopulated` JS event AFAIK

Comment: How do you populate your form?

Comment: @Woodrow "Are you loading a form and then wanting a JS event to fire after form is populated ? " yes precisely this. I am searching for something  similar to onchange which fires when form gets populated

Comment: How are you loading the form? Do you visit a page, and then JS goes out via AJAX to get data and populate the form? Or do you visit the page, and PHP populates the form inline inside the HTML file? Can you please provide some sample code that you've worked on for this?

Comment: The code is spring boot specific although I only want an event that fires when this form gets populated.

Answer (score 0):

so I solution was to use onload on the page body itself.